# regex to replace 0 in list but not 0 of 10, 20, 30, etc. - using js replace

Tags: javascript, regex, list, replace, numbers

I'm trying to create a regex to replace zeros in list with an empty value but not replace the zeros in ten, twenty, thirty, etc.

> list = 0,1,0,20,0,0,1,,1,3,10,30,0
>
> desired list = ,1,,20,,,1,,1,3,10,30,

Using this in the javascript replace function

Any help/tips appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be very simple using [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), `\b0\b`:

```
s = s.replace(/\b0\b/g, '');
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/ipuru4

Comment: Another option is using an array, but the OP asked for `.replace`: http://jsbin.com/ipuru4/2 . It seems a little weird to have a string in this form, so I'm giving this alternative.